# Session management when integrating Mattermost with another backend

Tags: mattermost

We building a backend for managing some core parts of our business and would like to have Mattermost for the communication part. The problem I see is seamless session management without having to dive into Mattermost's source code. Is there a way Mattermost can work as a widget and serve only the communication needs? Will it need to run in an IFrame? I'd appreciate some thoughts on that.

Comment: Would Single Sign On be sufficient to meet your needs? Mattermost E10/E20 Enterprise Edition [support LDAP and SAML](https://about.mattermost.com/features/#featuresCompare) for this respectively.

Comment: @George At my level it sounds too overwhelming! ^.^ I'm planning to now run it in an iFrame and have a script attempt a login as soon as the user logs in to the main application. Let's see how it goes!

Comment: @dotslash Hey, I am trying to do the same thing. I am using Apache 2.4. My mattermost servce is on the same server. Even though I have given same domain, I am getting error to call mattermost in the iframe.

Comment: @AparajitPUtpat I managed to do it in Nginx and wrote a blog post about it: https://ankushthakur.com/blog/how-to-run-mattermost-in-an-iframe/. You'll need to see how to translate it for Apache.